# Haskell program to replicate elements in List

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.
I am trying to write a program which given a list as an input replicates each element of list k times, where `k` = position of element in list.

e.g. `replic[5,6,7]` gives `[[5],[6,6],[7,7,7]]`.

Another condition is solution has to use `map` function.

Till now code I have written is :

```
replic [] = [] 
replic (x:xs) =  map (replicate 2 ) [x] ++ replic xs
```

This replicates every element twice as replicate has input parameter `2`.

What I need is `replicate` function should be given input as `1 ,2 ,3` in consecutive calls. So I need a counter. How can I use the counter there or do anything else that will give me position of element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on Satvik, the notation

```
[1..]
```

gives you an infinite list of numbers counting up.

The function `zip` associates allows you to merge two lists into a list of tuples

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
```

for example

```
> zip [1..] [5,6,7] 
[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]
```

this code associates each value in the list with its position in the list

now

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

repeats a value an arbitrary number of times.  Given these two components, we can design a simple function

```
replic xs = map (\(a,b) -> replicate a b) (zip [1..] xs)
```

which I would write pointfree as

```
replic :: [a] -> [[a]]
replic = map (uncurry replicate) . zip [1..]
```

this does exactly what you want

```
> replic [5,6,7]
[[5],[6,6],[7,7,7]]
```

Comment: Or, `replic = zipWith replicate [1..]`

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing this

Here is a solution similar to what you tried to do. zipping the list with list `[1..]` gives you the counter you wanted.

```
replic = repl . zip [1..]

repl [] = []
repl ((x,y):xs)  = (replicate x y) : (repl xs)
```

Another solution using just `map`

```
replic = map f . zip [1..]
    where
        f (c,l) = replicate c l
```

If you don't like idea of using `zip` you can also use `mapAccumL`

```
import Data.List

replic = snd . mapAccumL f 1
    where
        f a v = (a+1,replicate a v)
```

Comment: @AmolPatil See the improved solution

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would write:

```
replic = zipWith replicate [1..]
```

Now you can write your own `zipWith` yourself using `map`:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = map (uncurry f) $ zip xs ys
```

Note that you don't necessarily need an index, e.g.

```
import Data.List

replic xs = reverse $ transpose (tail $ inits $ reverse xs)
```

You can do something like this with `map` when using explicit recursion:

```
replic = f . map return where
  f [] = []
  f (x:xs) = x : f (map (\(x:xs) -> x:x:xs) xs)
```